# How to remove ubuntu from dual-boot system and install Elementary in its place?

Tags: boot

New Linux user here. So, I have a dual boot system set up with windows 10 on one end and Ubuntu on the other. But now I want to remove Ubuntu and install elementary OS with windows still intact. How do I do this?

Comment: Assuming you are installing from a DVD or a USB stick, when you boot from it, you will be asked where (as in on which partition) to install your OS. You can point to the previous Ubuntu partition. At this point, you will most probably get a warning saying there already is an OS installed on this partition and will be asked if you want to destroy it. You can say yes to that and go with the install process.

Answer (score 1):

- First make a backup of your whole disk e.g using `dd`, don't skip this buy an extra USB drive if you don't have enough backup space.
- don't wipe Ubuntu
- start elementary from USB and install in place of Ubuntu and make sure the bootloader is installed.

During the install `update-grub` will be run and it will detect Windows and add it to the grub menu.